# curl of css file only works if I execute the main page from browser

Tags: php, curl, archive

I'm trying to use cURL with PHP to retrieve CSS from this CSS file from archive
http://web.archive.org/web/20160312040057cs_/http://www.peer1.com/sites/all/modules/acro-custom/peer1_ribbonslider/peer1_ribbonslider.css?l

I am recieving this error :

> HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDDEN Server: Tengine/2.1.0 Date: Wed, 12 Apr 2017 12:30:04 GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive X-Archive-Wayback-Runtime-Error: RobotAccessControlException: Blocked by Robots X-Archive-Playback: 0 Content-Encoding: gzip

But After I execute the main page http://web.archive.org/web/20160312040057/https://www.peer1.com from browser , the curl request of that css file returns *200 OK*.

I tried to use http://waybackmachinedownloader.com/ but I am facing the same problem.

Please advice.